# Selenium cant find element created on the fly

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using a webpage that uses some funky JavaScript to generate the contents of drop down lists, each list based on the value of the previous drop down. Because of the way the page is constructed the drop downs are not Select elements, instead they use a UL generated on the fly. I am able to find the options of the first drop down using `driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(text))`. But when I try the same with the second drop down which is generated after the first is set, I always get a NoSuchElementException. My only idea is that Selenium WebDriver has cached the webpage before the element existed. Has anyone else experienced this before?

Edit: The element has definitely finished loading by the time the FindElement occurs. Sorry but I can't give you access to the site to test.

The first two drop down lists created are highlighted below:
[image]

WORKAROUND/UPDATE:
Currently the only workaround I can use is to send "Down" and "Enter" keys to the driver after clicking on the drop down box. No xPath commands have managed to locate the elements in the drop down list so at this point the question is still unanswered.

Comment: The thing is that selenium is faster than your browser: it checks the DOM **before** the element has been created.

Comment: Plus, there are thousand other reasons which can have impact on element load. Have you tried to find the element with any wait mechanism `selenium` provides?

Comment: I have added a 5 second wait and x3 retry wrapper around the method. I can actually inspect the element with DevTools and see that it is there and named correctly while WebDriver is still looking for it -.-

Comment: Have you tried explicit waits? What have you tried?

Comment: For debugging purposes I have an explicit wait of 5 seconds after setting the first drop down and before polling for the second. The implicit wait on the polling of each element is set to 10 seconds with 2 retries so in all it takes 35 seconds for the WebDriver exception. Given that the element actually loads in <1 second this should be ample